# ¿Por qué me carga mal los datos en el while? Me toma el último valor que debería finalizar el bucle

Tags: python

Tengo un problema con un bucle `while` en donde me realiza mal la carga de datos. El código es este:

```
def carga_de_datos():
    encomiendas = [] 

    municipio = input("Ingrese el nombre del municipio: ")

    while municipio != "Fin":
        establecimiento = input("Ingrese el establecimiento: ")
        cantidad_de_encomiendas_entregadas = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de encomiendas entregadas: "))
        dia_de_entrega = input("Ingrese el dia de la entrega: ")
        municipio = input("Ingrese el nombre del municipio: ")

        encomienda = [municipio, establecimiento, cantidad_de_encomiendas_entregadas, dia_de_entrega]

        encomiendas.append(encomienda)

    return encomiendas
```

y pasa que a la hora de ingresar el municipio, el establecimiento, la cantidad de encomiendas entregadas y la fecha, no me toma el valor la variable condicional ( en este caso `municipio = input("Ingrese el nombre del municipio: ")`) y me toma el último valor que debería finalizar el bucle. Quedando algo como esto:

Ingrese el nombre del municipio: florencio varela
Ingrese el establecimiento: qeqeqe
Ingrese la cantidad de encomiendas entregadas: 34
Ingrese el dia de la entrega: 08/07/22
Ingrese el nombre del municipio: quilmes
Ingrese el establecimiento: tututu
Ingrese la cantidad de encomiendas entregadas: 23
Ingrese el dia de la entrega: 31/08/22
Ingrese el nombre del municipio: Fin
[['quilmes', 'qeqeqe', 34, '08/07/22'], ['Fin', 'tututu', 23, '31/08/22']]

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es que el último `array` (`['Fin', 'tututu', 23, '31/08/22']`) no sea añadido?

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Buen día,

El problema es que tienes la variable `municipio` justo antes de adjuntar (`append`) los datos a tu lista, por lo que ese valor sobre escribe al que crees que es el valor del "ciclo" anterior.

Es por eso que parece que el nombre de los municipios se "recorre" a los datos anteriores y en lugar de obtener los municipios "florencio" y "quilmes" en tu resultado obtienes "quilmes" y "Fin"

**Nota:** No es buena práctica obtener los valores adentro de las funciones, normalmente es mejor obtener los valores y pasarlos como argumentos a la función, pero ignorare este punto para la solución expuesta en mi respuesta.

Lo que podrías hacer es que el `while` sea infinito hasta que `municipio` reciba la palabra "Fin" y utilizando `break` para interrumpir el ciclo infinito. Esto se podría lograr de la siguiente forma:

```
while True:
    municipio = input("Ingrese el nombre del municipio: ")
    
    if municipio == 'Fin':
        break  #Esto terminaría el while
```

Algo que se podría mejorar en tu código es que también se acepte `fin`, `FIN` o cualquier combinación de mayúsculas y minúsculas para la palabra "fin" para terminar el proceso, una forma fácil de lograrlo es convirtiendo siempre a minúsculas lo que reciba municipio, pero solo al compararlo con "fin" para que los nombres propios de los municipios sigan guardándose con mayúscula al inicio como deben escribirse los nombres propios. Para eso podemos utilizar el método `lower()` en el `if`

```
if municipio.lower() == 'fin':
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
def carga_de_datos():
    encomiendas = []
    
    while True:
        municipio = input("Ingrese el nombre del municipio: ")
        
        if municipio.lower() == 'fin':
            break
            
        establecimiento = input("Ingrese el establecimiento: ")
        cantidad_de_encomiendas_entregadas = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de encomiendas entregadas: "))
        dia_de_entrega = input("Ingrese el dia de la entrega: ")
        
        encomienda = [municipio, establecimiento, cantidad_de_encomiendas_entregadas, dia_de_entrega]

        encomiendas.append(encomienda)

    return encomiendas

carga_de_datos()
```

Ejemplo del funcionamiento:

```
Ingrese el nombre del municipio:  Florencio Varela
Ingrese el establecimiento:  Qeqeqe
Ingrese la cantidad de encomiendas entregadas:  34
Ingrese el dia de la entrega:  08/07/22
Ingrese el nombre del municipio:  Quilmes
Ingrese el establecimiento:  Tututu
Ingrese la cantidad de encomiendas entregadas:  23
Ingrese el dia de la entrega:  31/08/22
Ingrese el nombre del municipio:  fin

#Esto imprime la siguiente lista
[['Florencio Varela', 'Qeqeqe', 34, '08/07/22'],
 ['Quilmes', 'Tututu', 23, '31/08/22']]
```